# Incompatibility between isomath and \operatorname

Tags: isomath

The following MWE lead to an obvious problem:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{isomath}
\newcommand{\foo}{\operatorname{\alpha}}
\begin{document}
$\foo$
\end{document}
```

How do I avoid this conflict?

Comment: How important is it to you to use the `isomath` package? Put differently, are you open to using LuaLaTeX and the `unicode-math` package?

Comment: In a perfect world, ArXiv would allow LuaLaTeX :/

Comment: But `\operatorname` is only intended for log-like operators, not other symbols.  What is you use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<rant>`
Since ISO norms change so many conventions used for centuries in mathematics to establish some silly rules, it is expected that `isomath` does weird things.
`</rant>`

Here is a workaround: Greek letters can be set as `\mathnormal`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{isomath}

\newcommand{\foo}{\operatorname{\mathnormal{\alpha}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\baz}{\mathnormal{\alpha}}

\begin{document}

$\foo\baz$

\end{document}
```

A possible situation where one might want it:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{isomath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\amax}{\mathnormal{\alpha}-max}

\begin{document}

\[
\amax_{x\in[0,1]} f(x)=\beta
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

isomath (more precisely fixmath) redefines the greek symbols. Assuming that you use the package because you want this change, you probably should define your own greek symbols to use them inside `\operatorname`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{isomath}

%found in fontmath.ltx
\DeclareMathSymbol{\opalpha}{\mathord}{letters}{"0B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\opGamma}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"00}

\newcommand{\foo}{\operatorname{\opalpha\opGamma}}
\begin{document}
$\foo \neq \alpha\Gamma$
\end{document}
```

[image]